# Can an sqlite table have 100,000 records?

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, titanium-mobile

I have a web service returning almost 1 lac records (and increasing every day), to be consumded by a mobile application through a background service.

1. My idea is to save the records in an sqlite database, since it will be used offline as well, is this suggestible?
2. Is there a limitation to the size of an sqlite database to which it can grow?
3. Is there a better solution to consume such a huge data from the web service when i am offline

Comment: This is too broad - there isn't a simple answer that can be put in a few paragraphs. Also note that units such as "lac" are not universally understood.

Comment: You can limit your offline access to some certain records - Consider date as a factor.

Comment: So sorry laalto...I meant 100,000 records.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is more than a terabytes (that might be due to 32-bit architecture, although certain programs come with largefile support, allowing more that that). Fortunately `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` has following API call that returns the maximum size the database may grow to:

```
long getMaximumSize()
```

It returned me 1 TB, sqlite is a good option, it will take up all the memory you have in the device.